# Meaning of |t| in Ruby's create_table

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

What does `|t|` refer to in the following block of Ruby code?

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string :name
end
```

Comment: it says it [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table): `create_table() passes a TableDefinition object to the block.`

Comment: you can find out by doing a `puts t.inspect` on a line before `t.string :name` to see what exactly it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it being similar to writing your migration like this:

```
t = TableCreator.new
t.table_name = 'products'
t.string 'name'
t.save
```

The method `create_table` has been defined as something like this in the Rails migrator:

```
def create_table(name)
  creator = TableCreator.new(db_connection: current_connection)
  creator.table_name = name
  yield creator # this is the line that creates the |t| in your question
  t.save
end
```

This allows your migration to look like:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string :name
end
```

Which is a lot prettier and simpler for you to write as you don't have to for example call `.save` yourself.

Calling it `t` is completely up to you, it's just a local name. You could just as well write:

```
create_table :products do |table|
  table.string :name
end
```

Opinion: This is very basic "Hello World!" -level Ruby and you might want to learn some of the language basics before diving in into something as complex as Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Google for `ruby block yield`.

Inside `create_table`, someone constructed a `t = TableDef.new` or similar, and then called `yield(t)`. That passes the object into the block for the lines inside the block to use.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is really more complex than this, but maybe this can give an idea:

```
def create_table(table)
  p table
  p yield table
end

create_table 'products' do |t|
  t.insert t.size, '_table'
end

#=> "products"
#=> "products_table"
```

To keep it short I used the String class calling the method insert on 'products'.
But if you want to dig deeper in rails source: [create_table](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L289)

`t.class #=> String` in this example.

`t.class #=> ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition` in Rails with SQLite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

t is a block parameter which refers to product table upon which we are performing  operations to create column and set its type,go through iterators in ruby you will get the purpose of t being here.